# Discord bot C# not executing/reading commands

Tags: c#, discord

```
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace Leaf
{
    class Leaf
    {
        [Command("!!Gpurge")]
        [RequireBotPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        [RequireUserPermission(Discord.GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
        [Alias("Clear", "delete")]
        public async Task Purge(IUserMessage msg, int num = 100)
        {
        var purgeMessage = await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("!!Gpurge");
            var lastMessageID = purgeMessage.Id;
        if (num <= 100)
        {
            var messageToDelete = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(lastMessageID, Direction.Before, 15).OfType<IUserMessage>().ToList();
            await purgeMessage.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
```

**I changed to to a prefix using !!G with purge being a command to delete what however many messages within the 1-100 range but sadly, it does not read nor respond in the discord app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Discord.NET, checking if the message is a command via prefix should be already handled by an async handler.

If you followed the documentation/source-code's example, you can search up `HandleCommandAsync` function somewhere in your file.

Basically from the documentation's example, it looks like this:

```
private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        // Bail out if it's a System Message.
        var msg = arg as SocketUserMessage;
        if (msg == null) return;

        // Create a number to track where the prefix ends and the command begins
        int pos = 0;
        // Replace the '!' with whatever character
        // you want to prefix your commands with.
        // Uncomment the second half if you also want
        // commands to be invoked by mentioning the bot instead.
        if (msg.HasCharPrefix('!', ref pos) /* || msg.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref pos) */)
        {
            // Create a Command Context.
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);

            // Execute the command. (result does not indicate a return value, 
            // rather an object stating if the command executed succesfully).
            var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, pos, _services);

            // Uncomment the following lines if you want the bot
            // to send a message if it failed (not advised for most situations).
            //if (!result.IsSuccess && result.Error != CommandError.UnknownCommand)
            //    await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
        }
    }
```

Notice the part `msg.HasCharPrefix('!', ref pos)`?
Basically it checks if the message contains the prefix you wanted before it tries to executes a command. If it doesn't, then it does nothing.
(Do note that `msg.HasStringPrefix()` exists too!)

Comment: Wen Qin, i inserted the code and i narrowed down the lines to 3 lines of error, but in those errors i do not know why it isn't recognizing the _services _commands and _client

Comment: The code is extracted from the documentation's example. _client would be your declared `DiscordSocketClient`, _commands would be your declared `CommandService` and finally _services is your `IServiceProvider`. You can check out the documentation's tutorial here: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/getting_started/intro.html